# How do I perform the following SQL (or PL/SQL) Query

Tags: sql, plsql

If facing the following requirement: The user needs a table where he can see an employeeID, employeeName and the days where employees weren't working. The raw data is stored in the following tables:

```
Employee: Emp_ID, Emp_Name

WorkDays: Emp_ID, Date
```

The process is that everytime an employee has worked, his ID and the date of the day is inserted into the WorkDays table.

Now I need a SQL or PL/SQL Query where I choose a date range (f.e. between 2021-10-01 and 2021-11.01) and for every employee who hasn't worked on at least 1 day during that time (meaning there is a row "missing" in the WorkDays table for a particular ID and Date), he is displayed in one row with the dates he hasn't worked. The dates are all in one column of the row, f.e. seperated by commas.

For better understanding, if there are two employees who haven't worked during that time the final table should look something like this:

```
Emp_ID | Emp_Name |             Hasn't Worked               |
1      | John     |      2021-10-01, 2021-10-03, 2021-10-06 |
3      | Mary     |      2021-10-02, 2021-10-03             |
```

I don't want my code to get done for me but instead get help with the problem of querying a table where i have to loop trough the data and display multiple results (the dates) in one corresponding row.

Thanks a lot for help!
Jack

Comment: to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: 1NF (First Normal Form) Rules: Each table cell should contain a single value; Each record needs to be unique. Hasn't Worked 2021-10-01, 2021-10-03, 2021-10-06 is not in 1NF. Correct you table.

Comment: @RiggsFolly you are right! Wasn't my Intention to get my code done I just could't figure out a way to describe my specific problem understandable therefore I thought it would be easier to describe to whole requirement. Thanks!

Comment: @HalleyOliveira True, this would be a 1NF violation but I'm not trying to store the data but instead only display it where I thought in general this is possible f.e. with virtual columns that consist of "emp_name || ',' || emp_lastname"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a row generator to create a calendar and then use a `PARTITION OUTER JOIN` and find the non-matched rows and then aggregate:

```sql
WITH calendar (day) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2021-10-01' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT day + 1 FROM calendar WHERE day < DATE '2021-11-01'
)
SELECT w.emp_id,
       MAX(emp_name) AS emp_name,
       LISTAGG(TO_CHAR(c.day, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.day)
         AS non_work_days
FROM   calendar c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN workdays w
       PARTITION BY (w.emp_id)
       ON (c.day = w."DATE")
       LEFT OUTER JOIN employee e
       ON (w.emp_id = e.emp_id)
WHERE  w."DATE" IS NULL
GROUP BY w.emp_id;
```

or you can use `CROSS JOIN`:

```sql
WITH calendar (day) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2021-10-01' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT day + 1 FROM calendar WHERE day < DATE '2021-11-01'
)
SELECT e.emp_id,
       MAX(e.emp_name) AS emp_name,
       LISTAGG(TO_CHAR(c.day, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.day)
         AS non_work_days
FROM   calendar c
       CROSS JOIN employee e
       LEFT OUTER JOIN workdays w
       ON (c.day = w."DATE" AND e.emp_id = w.emp_id)
WHERE  w."DATE" IS NULL
GROUP BY e.emp_id;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Employee (Emp_ID, Emp_Name) AS
SELECT 1, 'Alice' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Beryl' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE WorkDays (Emp_ID, "DATE") AS
WITH calendar (dt) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2021-10-01' + LEVEL - 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 32
)
SELECT 1, dt FROM calendar WHERE dt NOT IN (DATE '2021-10-01', DATE '2021-10-03', DATE '2021-10-06')
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, dt FROM calendar WHERE dt NOT IN (DATE '2021-10-02', DATE '2021-10-03')
```

Both output:

> | EMP_ID | EMP_NAME | NON_WORK_DAYS |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Alice | 2021-10-01, 2021-10-03, 2021-10-06 |
> | 2 | Beryl | 2021-10-02, 2021-10-03 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=baf7923454817ab17b283f94aa084598)*

Comment: Partition outer join syntax was awesome.